# Google Play Developer Console Stack Trace showing too many methods

Tags: android, stack

We're looking at stack traces for crashes for our app on Google Play Developer Console.  We've uploaded the mapping file to deobfuscate the stack trace and that seems to be working.

However, something we've noticed is that the stack seems to show multiple methods in each part of the "chain".  Not just one method in each part like a regular stack trace.  Is there something we're doing wrong?  It makes it difficult to zone in on the issue since there are multiple permutations to consider.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.HashMap.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at com.ourdomain.ourapp.package1.package2.populateDefaults(package2.java)
                                                    ifResetNeeded(package2.java)
                                                    getFriendlyPageName(package2.java)
                                                    trackourdomainCustomerIDTO(package2.java)
at com.ourdomain.ourapp.ui.AccountLoginActivity.firepackage1LoginEvent(AccountLoginActivity.java)
at com.ourdomain.ourapp.ui.AccountLoginActivity.onToolBarCreated(AccountLoginActivity.java)
                                                      access$200(AccountLoginActivity.java)
                                                      access$400(AccountLoginActivity.java)
at com.ourdomain.ourapp.ui.AccountLoginActivity$5.onSuccess(AccountLoginActivity.java)
```

In the example above, it's not clear if the exception occurred in populateDefaults or ifResetNeeded or getFriendlyPageName or trackoutdomainCustomerIDTO

Comment: it duplicated the first one, maybe it crashed twice.

Comment: I've changed the stack trace to avoid confusion.